# Javascript can't import an existing constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to import a constant from one file to another.

This is the file that exports the constant:

```
import {
  GET_CATALOGS,
  GET_CATALOGS_SUCCESS,
  SHOW_MESSAGE,
  ON_CRUD_POPULATE_LIST,
  CRUD_POPULATE_LIST_SUCCESS
  ON_CRUD_FETCH_NEXT_PAGE,
  CRUD_FETCH_NEXT_PAGE_SUCCESS,
  ON_CRUD_FETCH_PREVIOUS_PAGE,
  CRUD_FETCH_PREVIOUS_PAGE_SUCCESS,
  ON_CRUD_FETCH_RECORD,
  CRUD_FETCH_RECORD_SUCCESS,
  ON_CRUD_CREATE,
  CRUD_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  ON_CRUD_UPDATE,
  CRUD_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
  ON_CRUD_DELETE,
  CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS
 } from 'constants/ActionTypes';

export const getCatalogs = (group) => {
  return {
    type: GET_CATALOGS,
    payload: group
  };
};

export const getCatalogsSuccess = (catalogs) => {
  return {
    type: GET_CATALOGS_SUCCESS,
    payload: catalogs
  }
};

export const showCatalogsMessage = (message) => {
  return {
    type: SHOW_MESSAGE,
    payload: message
  };
};

export const setCurrentCatalog = (catalog) => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_CATALOG,
    payload: catalog
  }
};

export const crudPopulateList = (catalog) => {
  return {
    type: ON_CRUD_POPULATE_LIST,
    payload: catalog
  }
};

export const crudPopulateListSuccess = (page) => { /// This is the constant that can't be imported
  return {
    type: CRUD_POPULATE_LIST_SUCCESS,
    payload: page
  }
};

export const crudFetchNextPage = () => {
  return {
    type: ON_CRUD_FETCH_NEXT_PAGE,
    payload: null
  }
};

export const crudFetchNextPageSuccess = (page) => {
  return {
    type: CRUD_FETCH_NEXT_PAGE_SUCCESS,
    payload: (page)
  }
};

export const crudFetchPreviousPage = () => {
  return {
    type: ON_CRUD_FETCH_PREVIOUS_PAGE,
    payload: null
  }
};

export const crudFetchPreviousPageSuccess = (page) => {
  return {
    type: CRUD_FETCH_PREVIOUS_PAGE_SUCCESS,
    payload: (page)
  }
};

export const crudFetchRecord = (id) => {
  return {
    type: ON_CRUD_FETCH_RECORD,
    payload: id
  }
};

export const crudFetchRecordSuccess = (record) => {
  return {
    type: CRUD_FETCH_RECORD_SUCCESS,
    payload: record,
  }
};

export const crudCreate = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: ON_CRUD_CREATE,
    payload: payload
  }
};

export const crudCreateSuccess = (record) => {
  return {
    type: CRUD_CREATE_SUCCESS,
    payload: record
  }
};

export const crudUpdate = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: ON_CRUD_UPDATE,
    payload: payload
  }
};

export const crudUpdateSuccess = (record) => {
  return {
    type: CRUD_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
    payload: record
  }
};

export const crudDelete = (id) => {
  return {
    type: ON_CRUD_DELETE,
    payload: id
  }
};

export const crudDeleteSuccess = (id) = {
  return {
    type: CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS,
    payload: id
  }
};
```

And this is the file where I try to import the constant:

```
import {all, call, fork, put, takeEvery} from "redux-saga/effects";
import {catalogs} from 'backend/Catalogs';
import {
  GET_CATALOGS,
  CRUD_POPULATE_LIST
} from "constants/ActionTypes";
import {
  getCatalogs,
  getCatalogsSuccess,
  showCatalogsMessage,
  crudPopulateListSuccess /// Here is where I try to import the constant
} from 'actions/Catalogs';

const getCatalogsRequest = async (group) =>
  await catalogs.getCatalogs(group)
    .then(catalogsList => catalogsList)
    .catch(error => error);

function* getCatalogsListFromRequest({payload}) {
  const {group} = payload;
  try {
    const catalogsList = yield call(getCatalogsRequest, group);
    if (catalogsList.message) {
      yield put(showCatalogsMessage(catalogsList.Message));
    } else {
      yield put(getCatalogsSuccess(catalogsList))
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(showCatalogsMessage(error));
  }
}

export function* getCatalogsList() {
  yield takeEvery(GET_CATALOGS, getCatalogsListFromRequest);
}

const crudPopulateListRequest = async (url) =>
await catalogs.crudPopulateList(url)
  .then(page => page)
  .catch(error => error);

function* crudPopulateListFromRequest({payload}) {
  const {catalog} = payload
  try {
    const page = yield call(crudPopulateListRequest, catalog.url)
    if (page.message) {
      yield put(showCatalogsMessage(page.list));
    } else {
      yield put(crudPopulateListSuccess(page));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(showCatalogsMessage(error));
  }
}

export function* crudPopulateList() {
  yield takeEvery(ON_CRUD_POPULATE_LIST, crudPopulateListFromRequest);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(getCatalogsList),
    fork(crudPopulateList),
    fork(crudFetchNextPage),
    fork(crudFetchPreviousPage),
    fork(crudFetchRecord),
    fork(crudCreateRecord),
    fork(crudUpdateRecord),
    fork(crudDeleteRecord)
  ]);
}
```

I can se that the constant exists, just like the constants imported previously but, nevertheless, I get this error:

[image]

I can't notice what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did u try close your ide and re-start again ? Sometimes, its happening about ide and webpack.

Comment: @HuLi ViCa are you sure is this right way..... import {getCatalogsSuccess
} from 'actions/Catalogs'; instead of import {getCatalogsSuccess
} from './actions/Catalogs';

Comment: @OzanManav that was it. Thanks a lot.